# JS form validation function not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="valform();return false;">
    <input id="username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And the following js code:

```
function checkFull(id) {
    var input = $('#' + id).val();  
    if (input == "") {
        return false;   
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

    function valform() {

if (!checkFull('username')) {
            $('#userfield').show(); 
        }
        else {
            $('#userfield').hide(); 
        }

        if (checkFull('username')) {
            form.submit();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

The form will submit even if the username field is empty, but if I add `return false;` to the first `else` statement under the `valform` function, it won't submit it if the username is empty.. Why doesn't it work as it is now?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? are you trying to send "username" to a different page? where's "userfield" declared?

Comment: @ClydeFrog userfield is just a small error message saying ``You have to fill in your username``. I'm trying to get the form NOT to submit if the username is not filled. I know I can write this code better but wondering why at the moment it's submitting while the username is emtpy

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript EXAMPLE](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_validation)

OR

[jQuery EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TRdzC/1/)

HTML

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>​
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").submit(function(){
        if ($("#textfield").val() == '') {
            return confirm("It's empty... but maybe you want it that way :)");
        }
    });
});​
```